# .NET: bundling all files in one installation

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have a vb.net application

i published it

it made an app files diretory, setup.exe, and some other file

i need everything to be in one file because the users are not very computer savy

is there a way to bundle everything in one installation file?

Comment: You can use WiX (Windows Installer XML) to create a setup file for you (.msi).  There's a pretty large barrier to learning WiX for creating a simple msi, but it is worth it once you know how to use it.  To overcome the learning curve, you can use something like WarSetup (http://warsetup.jgaa.com/) which will generate the project for you.

Comment: Another free alternative is NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bundle the files into a self-extracting ZIP file.

Comment: can u tell me how to do this please

Comment: +1 for something that should be easy, but I've seen people run a self-extracting ZIP and freak out because it wasn't as mindless of an operation as clicking 'Next' three times.  Sometimes, users just make things harder.

Comment: Press Start, Run, type `IExpress`, and follow the wizard.  You can also use WinZip.

Comment: thank you very much, unfortunately this is not working because it will not let me add a whole directory track, only files in the same folder

Comment: You can also use WinZip or 7Zip.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ILMerge](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMerge.aspx). It will allow you to merge multiple assemblies into 1. You could set it up in a Post Build Event to merge all of your assemblies into 1 exe.

Comment: +1 I've never used ILMerge.  Do you know if it will also add dependent files as resources?